# Drupal: Feed module imported items cannot be searched

Tags: php, drupal, import, content-management-system, drupal-feeds

I have created nodes from data imported from a csv file to my drupal site using Feeds module.
The import is successful and I can even see in views and also inside the contents.
However, when I try to search using the default drupal search or view's exposed filters, only some of the imported items are returned.
What could allow me to return contents what I am searching for from the Feeds module imported items?
Could it affect the search if my contents are in Japanese and the drupal site in English?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say whether or not the language is an issue. The reason why a view with filters wouldn't return anything would mainly be because of missing data or due to a filter which excludes the nodes.

For the search you have to run cron in order for the data to be indexed. Only indexed data can be found with the core search. You can run cron from the Status page, and on the Search settings page you can see the status of the search index. When the index is at 100% all your nodes should be found in the search.

Drupal 7:
http://www.example.com/admin/reports/status
http://www.example.com/admin/config/search/settings

Drupal 6:
http://www.example.com/admin/reports/status
http://www.example.com/admin/settings/search

Comment: thanks enzipher
it seems like the problem is with indexing 
I currently have 0% indexed
When I start cron job, it finishes in 1 or 2sec saying cron successfully completed
I checked the search API and found that the default node index was disabled
I think I should enable it to index my contents but the checkbox to enable the index appears dimmed.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Aha. It sounds like you are using Drupal 7 and the Search API module, and not the core search module. If the checkbox is dimmed you probably need to add a server. If you want to search the Drupal database I believe you could use the [search_api_db module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_db). I have not used this module much so I can't really help you there. You should probably ask a new question, or update this one to reflect the actual problem if you need help with that.